# Visual Studio 2008 + MOSS 2007 - An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: 2007, visual-studio

I followed the instructions given in the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297200%28d=printer,v=office.12%29.aspx

I copy the web application project from my Visual Studio 2008 to the MOSS 2007 folder and receive the error "An unexpected error has occurred"

May I know if I am missing something else?

Extra Info
[1] The project template is - "A blank ASP.NET Web site (.NET Framework 3.5)" using C#
[2] When I try to build the web site, I received a error 'Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content Controls'

Comment: If I used the project template - "A project for creating an application with a Web user interface (.NET Framework 3.5)" - which is a ASP.NET Web Application, I will have the error - "Unknown error". Is there a way to find out what "Unknown error" was?

Comment: You can resolve the error details in SharePoint logs, go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\` and sort descending by Date, and there will be the text log file, which you could search by correlation ID. Or you can use some tool like SharePoint Diagnostics Studio.

Comment: @Omlin, I don't really get what you mean by correlation ID. From what I can see as column header is - Timestamp, Process, TID, Area, Category, EventID, Level, Message & Correlation

Comment: @omlin, May I know where can I get the SharePoint Diagnostics Studio? - is it also free and does it support SharePoint 2007? (I found another one which is Administration Toolkit that also contain the SharePoint Diagnostics Studio - but it is for SharePoint 2010. - Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20022)

Comment: @omlin, I notice that when I try to repeat the same steps again up till the error message was displayed, the logs stop logging any errors. It has been like more than 45 minutes and no messages was recorded into the log. Is there anyway to find what has happen?

Comment: Correlation ID is inside Message column. Usually it is shown on site when the error is occured, next to the error message. And I confess, Diagnostics Studio is only for SP2010. For more info about SharePoint ULS logs you can check out this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/944/location-of-sharepoint-error-log

Comment: @omlim, unfortunately, for both error - "An unexpected error has occurred" and "Unknown error" did not come with any Correlation ID. Also, the logs files you are referring to are those label in this format - <server_name>-YYMMDD-HHMM.log, right (where YYMMDD is year month day and HHMM is hour minute)?

Comment: I saw that the error (for the "An unexpected error has occurred") was on - "Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException  Exception Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication1._Default'. " The another error has "transform" from "Unknown error" to blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Larry  go into the web.cofig file of the sharepoint site not the .net site you are creating and turn off custom errors this will get rid of that helpful sharepoint error also set callstack to true which will allow you to see the well, callstack.

Doing this will give you a better error, you can also look in the event log to see whats under applications

Comment: May I know which folder I can find out the web.config file you are referring to and where can I find the callstack?

Comment: Sorry Larry this is really late but you can find the web.config in c:\intpub\wwwroot\wss\virtual directories\yoursite.  You have probably already found it and sorted your problem but there it is for anyone else